# 'Gigabit' Ethernet Port Tester?

Tags: networking, hardware, port, local-area-network, gigabit-ethernet

A quick google search shows there seems to only exist handheld testers for 10/100 Ethernet ports. Any ideas why that is and where we could find one that works with a Gigabit LAN? Perhaps the 10/100 would work.

Comment: A simple google reveiled this: http://www.directindustry.com/prod/jdsu/ethernet-network-testers-21029-483649.html

Comment: Are you trying to test the cabling, or are you trying to test the switch ports/computers?  If you are testing cabling, then you should be searching for a tester for a given cabling standard.

Comment: Product or service recommendations, including 'does this exist' questions, are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq). They tend to be spam magnets for any company that DOES provide whatever is being searched for.

Comment: My reason for posting this questions stems from the fact that a simple 10/100 cat5 tester can be found  online for $39.00. (I know how to use Google) However, it does not claim to have the ability to test Gigabit ports. I find it puzzling that the device mentioned above in response to my question, and all the devices I was able to dig up, allows me to "request a quote", but not purchase. It's as if I was looking to purchase an X-ray machine.

Comment: A tester that you are getting for $39 is a simple continuity tester.    You can get the same results with cheap [Multimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter).  While that type of tester is somewhat useful, it really doesn't tell you anything at all about the ability of the cable to transmit at a given speed.  Any tester actually able to certify cables for CAT5/CAT6/etc specs is going to you cost somewhere in the $1,000-5,000 range.

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to see if the port is active without needing to plug in my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

There are true gigabit testers out there from Fluke, Blackbox, etc. but if all you are wanting to know is if the cable wiring is correct after you build a cable, then a 10/100 tester will work just fine.

Cat5e requirements are listed here:  http://www.techrepublic.com/article/get-it-done-make-sure-your-network-cabling-is-ready-for-gigabit-speeds/5031804  for reference...if your 10/100 tester can test and certify cat5e cables, then you are fine.